# Espresso Logic Minimization for Mac OS X

Tags: logic, minimization

Can somebody giving a working (meaning they tested it) Espresso that will work on Mac OS X?

I have a .pla file that I'd like to run.

Instructions on running the software wouldn't hurt, either.

Answer (score 0):

Espresso exists in [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/).  Once you have that installed, simply enter:

```
sudo port install espresso
```

from the terminal.  You can get help via:

```
man espresso
```

and

```
man 5 espresso
```

(for the input file format documentation)